# creating a TextView causes an exception

Tags: android, exception, textview

I've created an adapter that shows the results of this code.

```
public class Adapter_roadmap extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final  ArrayList<String> station_hour, station_hour_passed, station_name, station_name_passed, station_phoneNum;
        private final ArrayList<Boolean> station_passed;
        public   ArrayList<String> Station_hour_past, Station_hour_future, Station_name_past, Station_name_future, Station_phoneNum_past, Station_phoneNum_future;



        public Adapter_roadmap(Context context, ArrayList<String> station_name_values, ArrayList<String> station_name_passed_values, ArrayList<String> station_hour_values, ArrayList<String> station_hour__passed_values, ArrayList<String> station_phoneNum_values, ArrayList<Boolean> station_passed_values) {
            super(context, R.layout.listitem_road_map, station_name_values);
            this.context = context;
            System.out.println("initial past size: " + station_name_passed_values.size());
            System.out.println("initial past size: " + station_hour__passed_values.size());

            station_name        = station_name_values;
            station_name_passed = station_name_passed_values;
            station_hour        = station_hour_values;
            station_hour_passed = station_hour__passed_values;
            station_phoneNum    = station_phoneNum_values;
            station_passed      = station_passed_values;

        }



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("start of getView");

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_road_map, parent, false);

                    TextView textView_Names_passed = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LI_TV_Name_Passed);
                    TextView textView_Hour_passed = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LI_TV_Hour_passed);
                    TextView textView_Names = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LI_TV_Name);
                    TextView textView_Hour = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LI_TV_Hour);
                    textView_Names_passed.setText(station_name_passed.get(position));
                    textView_Hour_passed.setText(station_hour_passed.get(position));
                    textView_Names.setText(station_name.get(position));
                    textView_Hour.setText(station_hour.get(position));
```

When I tried to run the code, I've encountered the following exception :

```
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myt.mytguideapp, PID: 29764
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at Adapters.Adapter_roadmap.getView(Adapter_roadmap.java:90)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-22 11:49:04.748 29764-29764/com.myt.mytguideapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I tried debugging I noticed that the exception happened in these specific two lines:

```
textView_Names_passed.setText(station_name_passed.get(position));
textView_Hour_passed.setText(station_hour_passed.get(position));
```

and when I tried removing them there was no exception.
I need these 2 lines and they are critic for my app.
Why is there an extra index created?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` . This means you are trying to obtain data from an Array which isn't there.

The exception states that `Invalid index 4, size is 4`. Which tells you you are at index 4. and the size is only 4. (Note of course that the array starts at 0. so 4th index is trying to look for something of at least size 5).

I'd suggest you check if :

1. All data is set in the Array `station_name_passed` and
   `station_hour_passed`
2. Your not trying to set more fields than data you have
3. You start your index at 0
4. You are using the right index. You are using position for all 4 Arrays.

About point 4; it seems you have Names and Hours which you conditionally pass to Names_passed and Hour_passed. I'm just guessing this, but if you put in only the passed names and hours, you end up with less names and hours. This means that you have a smaller size of that Array. Looping through all Names and Hours will eventually cause the passed Arrays to go out of bounds, as they have less entries as the original set of names and hours

Comment: All the data in the arrays you've mentioned is checked. why the other textView don't throw any exceptions? why only these two checked arrays are making this problem?

Comment: Made a slight mistake. I meant station_name_passed  and station_hour_passed. I do not have enough information to know where you get the data from. But it you are using the dame position. So if station_name and station_hour have a bigger size. So they do not go out of bounds.

Comment: I also edited my answer a bit. Check it out and see if it helps

Comment: Thank for trying but nothing worked. I still don't know what caused the out of bound exception. What I did was adding this line before the problematic lines : 'if (position<=station_name_passed.size())'